# diff without including removed content

Tags: diff, patch

I'm using `diff` and `patch` to patch some files. In my situation, I am not permitted to distribute any of the original file.

Right now, the diffs look something like this:

```
1c1
< Hello, this is the original.
---
> Hey, this is the new version.
```

I don't want to (and for reasons *can't)* include the original lines. Is it possible to make a diff that doesn't include the original lines, just what *replaces* the original lines?

The closest I've found is using `diff -e` to generate an `ed` script, but it doesn't look like `ed` is installed by default on Debian. Is it possible to do this with `diff` and `patch`?

**EDIT:** For example, I want to take a file that looks like this:

```
Hello, this is a file.
It is pretty cool.
I wrote it in a text editor.
```

to a file like this:

```
Hello, this is a file.
It is kinda awesome.
I wrote it in a text editor.
```

A regular diff would include the original line, and look like this:

```
2c2
< It is pretty cool.
---
> It is kinda awesome.
```

I *don't want* the original line *("It is pretty cool.")* to even *be* in the diff file. I'd like a diff file that basically says 
replace line 2 with: It is kinda awesomewhich has all the needed info to patch, but includes none of the original content. Essentially, I want a diff that says "replace *whatever* is on line 2 with *this:"*.

Running `patch -e` to make an `ed` script generates all that I need, but I don't want to use that as ed isn't included in Debian by default.

```
2c
It is kinda awesome.
.
```

Comment: No ed?!?!? ed is the [standard text editor!](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

Comment: I was kind of surprised too, as it's part of POSIX, so it _should_ be in Debian.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your situation, but what about just providing the new file with instructions to copy it over the existing file?

Comment: Let me clarify: In my situation, I am not permitted to redistribute _any_ of the original content, so I can't include it in the patch.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm imagining a big of sed for each file  (sed 2s/.*/new text/; 5s/.*/other text/ ...). If you can't rely on -i being there for sed, you're also looking at working with temp files

Comment: why not just include `ed` w/ the patch file? i doubt seriously if anybody will quibble about you distributing *its* source.

Comment: Because then users have to trust me with their system, and I have to keep it updated, make sure I don't distribute buggy versions, etc. If I was going to do that, I could just distribute a different patching program.

Comment: @IBPX - i dont think so. it needn't be installed into the file hierarchy to be used...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture what I understand from the Q's comments, I'm going to answer that "no, it is not possible to do what you want with `diff` and `patch`", since they must include context, which includes content that you can't distribute.

Given that you can't rely on [`ed`](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) to be present, if you can rely on `sed` to be there, then you could loop through your changed files and update each one with a `sed` expression:

```
$ cp input tempfile && \
$ sed \
    -e '2s/.*/It is kinda awesome./' \
    -e '4s/.*/No really, this is line 4/' \
  tempfile > input && \
$ rm tempfile
```

I broke the commands up to hint at the possibility of a script-writing script that would generate the above commands, replacing "input" with the filename that needs to be changed and the "-e ..." lines with the content that needs to change. Here I'm changing whatever's on line 2 and line 4 with the corresponding text.

If you're concerned about "tempfile" colliding with an existing name, see if this spartan system has [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp). You could save some mktemp cycles by creating one temp file to (re)use for each input file.

If this ed-less system has a sed that supports the `-i` flag, then you can simplify that batch to:

```
$ sed -i.orig \
    -e '2s/.*/It is kinda awesome./' \
    -e '4s/.*/No really, this is line 4/' \
  input
```

mikeserv brings up a good point with sed's 'c' command; GNU sed appears to accept the replacement text on the same line as the 'c' command, but just in case yours doesn't, here's one option:

```
$ cat > patch.sed
2c\
this is the new line two
4c\
this is an awesomer line four
^D
$ sed -f patch.sed input > output ## or sed -i.orig -f patch.sed input
```

Comment: @mikeserv, I had trouble using c\ on the same line as the replacement text; see [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35323/sed-c-command) if you're still there. I like the 'c' idea; will rework the answer a bit

Comment: thats possible - its really not the correct way to do it, but i figured with the `-i` and the specified Debian environment i might get away w/ modifying your *(very good)* answer as little as possible while hopefully still marginally improving it and so omitted the correct newlines there. *(though you should remove the `-i` in my opinion...)*. I like your edit better. Options are *good*.

Comment: thanks, mike; I updated the answer. tmtowtdi! it's a good day when I can solve a problem *and* learn something!

Comment: Btw, @ibpx, be sure to escape / or ' characters in any replacement text, depending on the method you choose.

Comment: There's more than one way to do it -- sorry, must be a perl-ism

Answer (score -1):

```
diff file1  file2  | grep ^">"
```

comes to mind

Comment: I mean produce a file that can be applied over the original, without containing any of the original. That command just shows me what has changed, not even _where_ it has been changed.

Comment: can you update your question with a few of sample file contents ? I mean, provide dummy files' content to run `diff` on and the output you are trying to obtain as a result of this command

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score -2):

At least with GNU `diff`, it seems to be possible with suitable `LFMT` (line format) specifiers:

```
diff --new-line-format="replace line %-dn with:%c'\012'%L" --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= file1 file2
```

Tested with:

```
$ cat file1
Hello, this is a file.
It is pretty cool.
I wrote it in a text editor.

$ cat file2
Hello, this is a file.
It is kinda awesome.
I wrote it in a text editor.

$ diff --new-line-format="replace line %-dn with:%c'\012'%L" --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= file1 file2 
replace line 2 with: 
It is kinda awesome.
```